# Display errors in Angular when form invalid

Tags: angularjs

Is there an automated way in Angular to display the error messages for invalid form. For Example, I have the below. It indeed works well in that it doesn't allow the user to submit but it doesn't give the user any automatic feedback to tell them that elements are required. Isn't there an automatic way to get it to print a field is required message by the field if the form is invalid on submit?

```
           <div class="form-center">
    <form name="loginform" class="forms" ng-controller="controllers.LoginController">
        <fieldset>  <legend><h3>Account Login</h3></legend>

            <div class="advanced-search-item">
                <label>Username:</label><br /> <input type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required><span class="error" ng-show="submitted && loginform.username.$error.required">Required!</span>

            </div>

            <div class="advanced-search-item">
            <label>Password:</label><br /> 
                <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" required><span class="error" ng-show="submitted && loginform.username.$error.required">Required!</span>
            </div>


             <div class="advanced-search-item">
                 <a href="#" class="advanced-search-button submit-button" ng-disabled='!loginform.$valid' ng-click="submitted=true;loginUser()">Login</a>
            </div>


        </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add some spans to show errors beside input fields like below

```
<span class="error" ng-show="submitted && loginform.username.$error.required">Required!</span>

<span class="error" ng-show="submitted && loginform.password.$error.required">Required!</span>
```

Hopefully you can keep this text in red color, below is the CSS

```
.error {
    padding-left:10px;
    color: #F00;
}
```

when form is submitted and if there are errors it will show above spans

Hope this helps

Comment: It seems the submitted variable is set to true already when I get to the form initially... so the span displays immediately... Do I have something setup wrong?

Comment: what error do you see in console? Also you need to set `submitted=true;` when Login link is clicked `like ng-click="submitted=true;loginUser()"`, have you added angualar.js link correctly?

Comment: Actually now what happens with the corrected code above is that, it just submits the form anyway and doesn't disable the submit button... No errors in the console at all.